# DELL: Integrated screen freeze but sounds goes on : reinstall Intel graphics drivers

Tags: graphics, dell, freeze

I have a weird issue with my laptop : Dell XPS 15 9500 using Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Suddenly, when watching videos or playing game, the screen freezes but the sounds carries on. When using also an external monitor what can happen is that the integrated screen freezes, but everything is fine on the external monitor.

Putting the laptop to sleep is enough to unfreeze it, but it isn't a permanent solution.

I contacted Dell support, and the same problem is known also under Windows. Their solution is to reinstall Intel Graphics Command Center, and then reinstall Intel Graphics driver (version 27.20.100.9186 or newer). However, I don't know how to translate these operations on Ubuntu since there is no Intel Graphics Command Center on Ubuntu.

If anyone has a suggestion I am open to it.